# Remove date mutator in eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5.6, mutators

I have a model with a `created_at` value defined as a Unix timestamp.

I retrieve an instance of my model with `$model = Model::where(...)->first()`

When I `var_dump($model->created_at)` I get a `Illuminate\Support\Carbon` instance instead of my integer timestamp.

According to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) (*emphasis mine*):

> By default, Eloquent will convert the created_at and updated_at columns to instances of Carbon, which extends the PHP DateTime class to provide an assortment of helpful methods. You may customize which dates are automatically mutated, **and even completely disable this mutation, by overriding the $dates property of your model**

I've tried adding `protected $dates = []` to my model, but I still get the `Carbon` object instead of an integer.

If I disable timestamps (`public $timestamps = false;`) it works, but then I won't get my timestamp inserted when I create new entries - and I need that.

Comment: Have you tried `protected $timestamps = false`?

Comment: @thisiskelvin But if I disable $timestamps I don't get the created_at values in the table when I create a new entry. I still need that

Comment: You could add those back manually.

Comment: Also, you can then add model events/observer once the model is being created, updated, deleted. Would you like me to put within an answer?

Comment: That would work for me. Please do @thisiskelvin

Comment: Try @nakov answer first. I'll still post my answer.

Comment: What about using `$model->created_at->timestamp` instead of just `$model->created_at`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'integer'
];
```